# Filter nodes based on active context

Tags: 6

Is it possible to filter nodes based on whether a certain context (defined by context module) is active? I can't find a way to do this. I'm using Drupal 6 and context 6.x-3.0.

Let's say we have a certain menu path that activates a context. In this context I have a view and I need to filter nodes that belong to the context (that is they belong to the menu, that activates the context).

Comment: Please elaborate on the filtering. Do you want to filter the nodes from a view? On which pages are you seeing nodes that you need to be filtered out?

Answer (score 1):

Making context aware Views is not something you can easily do with Context module. That is I'm sure it would be possible, but it would require a lot of work.

Panels is designed to accomplish such tasks, with it's tight integration to views, it can pass arguments to views that you can use to determine what to display.

Answer (score 0):

[Views default argument from Context](http://drupal.org/project/views_arg_context) is a project that might help you out. (I've not used it yet, just remembered seeing it a while back.)

It looks like you'll need to write a small module with a bit of glue code. See these configuration notes in the issue queue for the module:
http://drupal.org/node/774966